# AUTOCAD Slice a Polyline .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, autocad

I'm trying to slice an imported polyline along the Z Axis. It imports fine and in the correct orientation (vertical). I can slice 3D objects fine, I just can't seem to find the correct way to do it for slicing a Polyline.

Hoping someone can help me with the code below. Also below is the AutoCAD error I get when I try to run the code.

Thanks in advance.

```
        <CommandMethod("SlicePolyline")>
        Public Shared Sub SlicePolyline()

            Dim doc As Document = AutoCADApp.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument
            Dim db As Database = doc.Database
            Dim ed As Editor = doc.Editor

            Using tr As Transaction = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction()

                Dim pStrOpts As PromptStringOptions = New PromptStringOptions("FilePath: ")
                pStrOpts.AllowSpaces = True
                Dim FileName As PromptResult = ed.GetString(pStrOpts)

                Dim promptPointResult = ed.GetPoint(vbLf & "Specify point: ")
                If promptPointResult.Status <> PromptStatus.OK Then Return
                Dim Origin = promptPointResult.Value

                Dim ObjId As ObjectId
                Dim bt As BlockTable = db.BlockTableId.GetObject(OpenMode.ForRead)
                Dim btr As BlockTableRecord = bt(BlockTableRecord.ModelSpace).GetObject(OpenMode.ForWrite)

                'Import the object
                Using dbInsert As New Database(False, True)
                    dbInsert.ReadDwgFile(FileName.StringResult, IO.FileShare.Read, True, "")
                    ObjId = db.Insert(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileName.StringResult), dbInsert, True)
                End Using

                'Explode the object
                Dim acPoly As BlockReference = New BlockReference(New Point3d(Origin.X, Origin.Y, Origin.Z), ObjId)
                Dim acDBObjColl As DBObjectCollection = New DBObjectCollection()
                acPoly.Explode(acDBObjColl)


                Dim pline As New Solid3d()
                Dim currentSpace As BlockTableRecord = DirectCast(tr.GetObject(db.CurrentSpaceId, OpenMode.ForWrite), BlockTableRecord)

                Using plineCollection As New DBObjectCollection()
                    plineCollection.Add(pline)
                    Using regionCollection As DBObjectCollection = Region.CreateFromCurves(acDBObjColl)
                        Using region As Region = DirectCast(regionCollection(0), Region)
                            Using poly As New Polyline()

                                Dim pxs As Point3dCollection = New Point3dCollection()
                                pxs.Add(Origin)
                                Dim splited As DBObjectCollection = poly.GetSplitCurves(pxs)

                                btr.AppendEntity(poly)
                                tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(poly, True)

                            End Using
                        End Using
                    End Using
                End Using

                tr.Commit()

            End Using

        End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If this is simple polyline I thing the easies way is to use `GetSplitCurves`

```
Point3dCollection pxs = new Point3dCollection();
pxs.Add(Origin);
DBObjectCollection splited = poly.GetSplitCurves(pxs);
```

Comment: Thanks @CAD Developer for your answer. I've tried adding in your code and also modifying it but can't get it to work. The issue is with the poly.GetSplitCurves.  Is there something I'm missing here? Appreciate the help.

Comment: What do You mean by "I've tried"?  what "modifying" You have done? What do You mean "can't get it to work"? and what is "The issue"? What is the expected result, and what result do You get?

Comment: I've edited the above code to show what I've tried along with the error that AutoCAD is throwing. Hope this helps. Thanks @CAD Developer.

Comment: Your 'poly' is just new polyline. Without any geometry. 
'acPoly' is a 'BlockReference' block may be batch of any entity. You need to extract polylines from Your block. if any, cause block may have no any polylines. 
To simplify that I recomend You to do simple test. Just write command where draw single polyline and split this. without any import, blocks and so on.

Comment: If You just split single polyline, You will have the answer to Your question, if any new question will be needed,please ask it in separate threat.